# trying to split a string using re.sub and split method

Tags: python

I have the following str:

```
str='hola.mami.gusto'
```

I am looking forward to remove all the substring (and including) the last '.'

I tried a simple

```
str.split('.',1)
```

However it separates :

```
['hola', 'mami.gusto']
```

instead of my desired output:

```
['hola.mami', 'gusto']
```

Then i tried a regex:

```
answer= re.sub("\.", "", str,-1)
```

Thinking this will replace everything after the last '.' by "".

But nothing changed

Comment: Beware of using `str` as a variable name because it is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your "desired output" you can just go with [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) function (for splitting from the *right*):

```
s = 'hola.mami.gusto'
res = s.rsplit('.', 1)
print(res)   # ['hola.mami', 'gusto']
```